# Auto remove out of stock items in cart then notify account user - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I wish to allow customers to add items to their Woocommerce cart and leave it there for as long as they want, so they can add to the cart at their leisure. Any lines that go out of stock need to automatically be removed from the cart and a message to show that this has occurred. Something like "All out of stock items have been removed from the account as they are no longer available".

So far I have tried this

```
public function is_in_stock() {
return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_is_in_stock', 'instock' === $this->get_stock_status(), $this );
}
function notes_in_cart() {
 global $woocommerce;

if ( ! $_POST || ( is_admin() && ! is_ajax() ) ) {
    return;
}

if ( isset( $_POST['post_data'] ) ) {
    parse_str( $_POST['post_data'], $post_data );
} else {
    $post_data = $_POST; // fallback for final checkout (non-ajax)
}

if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() ){

    // set $out_of_stock_exists to false by default
    $out_of_stock_exists = false;
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        if($values['data']->backorders_allowed()){ //check if backorders are allowed on this product
            // get the stock quantity - returns the available amount number
            $stock_info = $values['data']->get_stock_quantity();

            if($stock_info < $values['quantity']){ 
    set $out_of_stock_exists to true and stop foreach execution
                $out_of_stock_exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    //if cart has items out of stock
    if ($out_of_stock_exists) {
        ?>
        <tr class="ceckoutStockMeta">
            <th>Item Shipments</th>
            <td>
                <p style="color: red;">*All out of stock items have been removed from your cart as they are no longer available.</p><br>
                <form>

                    <input type="radio" name="stockOp" id="stockOption1" value="ship" />
                    <label for="stockOption1">Ship what is available now</label><br>

                    <input type="radio" name="stockOp" id="stockOption2" value="hold" />
                    <label for="stockOption2">Wait and ship together</label>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php

    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total', 'notes_in_cart' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'notes_in_cart' );
```

I am not sure if all of this is necessary, considering backorders need to be disallowed anyway.

Can someone tell me if this is correct?

As for auto removal of out of stock lines from an account's cart, I am guessing that this will happen 'out of the box' with Woocommerce. Can someone please confirm this or provide a way to do it?

Thank you,
Bryan

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question asking for recommendation and how makes it very vague for any other user on Stack Overflow. Please refer to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include what you have done, where you are stuck and what you want it to do. Thanks =)

Comment: "My client wishes"   If you are incapable of doing specific development work for your client (due to lack of knowledge or otherwise) the best thing you can do for your client is tell them that so they can hire a dev who *is* capable.  You only waste your time and theirs otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @Minial I am new to this site, so will try to provide more detail in future. Have edited my original question to comply. Hope it is more suitable now. :)

Comment: @JustinR. that is not an ideal way to greet a new member to this site. I was told that stackoverflow was the best place to go for help with programming needs, yet the very first time I try to ask for help, I get slammed. Perhaps offering to fix my problem for a price would have been a better greeting.

Comment: People come to SO every day expecting others to write all of their code for them for free.  An even greater number of people, in general, take on dev jobs they are incapable of doing.  My statement stands true for anyone who is in the business of web development; it is nothing personal.  As your question was originally posted, it did not meet SO community guidelines. It lacked code and showed no research effort (hence the number of downvotes).  Like most others here, I'm happy to help answer questions when I can, for free, but I am not here to completely do other people's work.

Comment: Fair enough @JustinR. just be a bit more gentle next time, lol.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out where I was going wrong and I was totally on the wrong track. I am posting the correct code below, in case anyone else needs this functionality in the future. It does both, updates the cart when products are out of stock and leaves a new message at the same time.

```
/**
 * This code will automatically remove any out of stock items from a shopping cart.
 * This would be in cases when users add products to their cart and come back to it later.
*
*/
function orb_check_for_out_of_stock_products() {
if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
    return;
}

$removed_products = [];

foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $product_obj = $cart_item['data'];

    if ( ! $product_obj->is_in_stock() ) {
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
        $removed_products[] = $product_obj;
    }
}

if (!empty($removed_products)) {
    wc_clear_notices(); // remove any WC notice about sorry about out of stock products to be removed from cart.

    foreach ( $removed_products as $idx => $product_obj ) {
        $product_name = $product_obj->get_title();
        $msg = sprintf( __( "The product '%s' was removed from your cart because it is now out of stock. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.", 'woocommerce' ), $product_name);

        wc_add_notice( $msg, 'error' );
    }
}

}
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'orb_check_for_out_of_stock_products');
```

My thanks to those who offered their help and a big thank you to Svetoslav Marinov from http://orbisius.com/ for contacting me directly with his input. It was he who, led me in the right direction.

Feel free to update this code with any improvements you can identify.